# JQuery for loop, for vectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop

I am trying to make a vector calculator to practice my jquery skills and I have an Issue. I have a .option div where I have fields for the force and the angle. If I click the #calc_v button another field is inserted.

```
<div class="option">
   <h2>Vectors</h2>
<a class="close">Close X</a><br/>
<div id="move">1.<input type="number" step="0.01" id="N1"/> Newtons(or meters) à <input type="number" step="0.01" id="A1"/> Degrees
<br/></div>
<button id="calc_v">Calculer</button>

<a id="add_move">+ VECTOR</a>
<div id="log_v"></div>
```

here is my jquery code:

```
<script>
//vectors
var vector = 1;

$("#add_move").click(function () {
    vector++;
    $("#move").append(vector+".<input type='number' step='0.01' id='N"+vector+"'/> Newtons(ou mètres) à <input type='number' step='0.01' id='A"+vector+"'/> Degrées<br/>");
});

$("#calc_v").click(function(){
    var x_v = 0;
    var y_v = 0;
    var ite = 0;
    for(x=1; x <= vector; x++){
        //for each added vector give it a var name
        ite++;
        var f = "#N"+ite;
        var a = "#A"+ite;
        //then, find its value
        var force = $(f).val();
        var f_val = parseFloat(force);
        var angle = $(a).val();
        var a_val = parseFloat(angle);

        //analyse it
        var cons_x = ((f_val)*(Math.cos(a_val))) * (180 / Math.PI);
        var cons_y = ((f_val)*(Math.sin(a_val))) * (180 / Math.PI); 
        //add it to each x,y coords
        x_v += cons_x;
        y_v += cons_y;
    }
    $("#log_v").html("Coords: ("+ x_v + ","+ y_v + ") |f"+force +"|a"+ angle +"|i"+ ite+"|v"+vector);
});
```

Comment: So, what's your problem? And more important, what's your question?

Comment: It only returns the calculation for the last iteration

Comment: yes, it only prints the values from the last iteration, because your "logging" is outside the loop. And if you put it inside the lopp (as it is right now), it will also show only the last value, because it will overwrite the content of `#log_v` so fast that you only see the last value. There are a few things to improve in this code, check this fiddle out: https://jsfiddle.net/9yehsnb2/

Comment: made a little update, regarding the logging: https://jsfiddle.net/9yehsnb2/1/